# Run an imported Ansible playbook for each unique value in a set of host vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I've got a playbook which needs to run against my entire inventory, with a list of hostnames as an extra variable (`target_hosts`).

The hosts in `target_hosts` all have a `group_id` hostvar defined on them. I use the whole inventory because some ancillary hosts which correspond to the `group_id` var need per-group configuration to match in one section.

There will often be multiple `group_id` values associated with the hosts in the `target_hosts` list. I need to select the correct inventory group of ancillary hosts and import/run a playbook to configure both sets of servers partway through the main playbook.

This is what I currently do:

```
include_playbook: group-configure.yaml
vars:
  src_hosts: "group-{{ group_id }}-ancillary-1"
  dest_hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
```

I currently have to manually separate the `target_hosts` by `group_id` manually, then run the main playbook once for each. This has tons of unnecessary overhead.

What I really want to execute is this:

```
for each group of hosts from `target_hosts` with the same `group_id` hostvar:
  import and run group-configure.yaml with:
    src_hosts: "ancillary-{{ group_id }}"
    target_hosts: restricted to those with that value of `group_id`'
```

How can I do this? If the current way this is structured won't work, what's the best alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/add_host_module.html) combined with [`groupby`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#groupby) is what you are looking for, which will allow you to roll up those hosts by their attribute, and then run the playbook against them as if that group was defined already:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: no
  vars:
    list_of_name_groups: >-
        {%- set results = [] -%}
        {%- for g_id, items in (dict(hostvars) | dict2items | groupby("value.group_id")) -%}
        {%- for hostname in (items | map(attribute="key") | list) -%}
        {%- set _ = results.append({"group_id": g_id, "hostname": hostname}) -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ results }}
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: '{{ item.hostname }}'
      groups: ancillary-{{ item.group_id }}
    with_items: '{{ list_of_name_groups }}'

- hosts: ancillary-my-awesome-groupid
  # etc etc
```